# Select data by range in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

Suppose I have 500 records in `tbl_students`. I would like to select records starting from 50 and 250. I know I can use the following way in MySql.

```
SELECT *
FROM tbl_students
LIMIT 50,100;
```

I would like to know how to do this in SQL Server. After browsing I have found solution like this.

```
select top 100 * 
from tablename  
WHERE column_name BETWEEN 50 AND 250
```

The issue I am facing is I do not know the values of any column in the table, so I can't write the query like the above. In MySql we can just put the `limit` for the range without knowing the values inside the column.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Which **version** of SQL Server are you on? SQL Server **2012** introduced the `OFFSET .. FETCH` syntax to do this very easily..

Comment: Your first query makes no sense without an `ORDER BY` clause. How are you defining the first 100 records? Or the first 250 in your second query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using **SQL Server 2005/08**, then you could use a [CTE](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766(v=sql.105).aspx)...

```
;WITH cteRange as 
(
select *, rownumber=ROW_NUMBER() OVER (Order by field) 
from tablename  
)
SELECT * FROM cteRange WHERE rownumber BETWEEN 50 AND 250
```

if you have **SQL Server 2012**, then...

```
SELECT 
  *
FROM tablename  
 ORDER BY field
  OFFSET 50 ROWS 
  FETCH NEXT 200 ROWS ONLY
```

It would be useful to know *RDBMS* and also what columns you want to extract and Order by, instead of using `SELECT *...`

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT * FROM ( 
  SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY column_name ) as tbl_row FROM tbl_students
 ) tbl WHERE tbl_row >= 50 and tbl_row <= 250
```

I think this is one of way available for doing this in SQL Server above version 2005.

Answer (score 3):

It's not clear by what column(s) you want to sort. A table has no implicit order, so you cannot say "give me records between x and y" if you don't specify how you want to order the records.

However, assuming that `column_name` is the column that you want to use and you're using SQL Server 2005 or newer, you can use a `CTE` with `ROW_NUMBER` window function:

```
WITH CTE AS
(
   SELECT t.*, R = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY column_name)
   FROM dbo.TableName t
)
SELECT * FROM CTE WHERE RN BETWEEN 50 AND 250
```